# How to put Wordpress Profile Meta in different pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, profiles

I need three different pages showing different parts of one user profile on wordpress. Author.php is a standard feature and is great is loads on my website www.website.com/site1/user/nicename. However I want to have one profile which is sorted, but display the profile over three different areas of the website.

PLEASE NOTE: Username in this example would be joe-blogs1990 what ever the user decides, the nicename will be formatted joebloggs, first and surname combined for nice permalinks on wordpress.

```
www.website.com/site1/author/username
www.website.com/site2/agency/nicename
www.website.com/site3/meet-the-team/nicename
```

I simply wish to call user profile information in three different places, but they will have different information on each one, I’ve managed to create a place where everything is edited in one place, however to display information based on the URL is slightly bewildered me.

Here is what I have so far, but nothing is loading on any of the pages what im trying to achieve above.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>  

<?php $blogname = get_bloginfo('name'); if ( $blogname == 'site1' ) {
get_the_author_meta('description');
} ?>

<?php $blogname = get_bloginfo('name'); if ( $blogname == 'site2' ) { 
get_the_author_meta('first_name');
get_the_author_meta('last_name');
} ?>

<?php $blogname = get_bloginfo('name'); if ( $blogname == 'site3' ) {
get_the_author_meta('facebook_profile');
get_the_author_meta('twitter_profile');
} ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `echo` in Front of the `get_the_whatever` methods. All methods prefixed with `get_` just return `string`s; in order to see something you have to echo it.